# Jquery Form Validation Plugin Help

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-plugins

i using this JQuery Form Validation Plugin. https://github.com/posabsolute/jQuery-Validation-Engine

I am able to attach it to my form and validate it. i am not able to load the CSS file and position it in the right position.

http://bakasura.in/gaa/

Comment: `options is undefined` error display when click on submit..there may b some syntactical error

Comment: Thanks! i am not able to get the error in Firebug. Weird :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you got a JavaScript error instead. Check it out first.

```
options is undefined
_validateField(field=[input#last_name.validate[required,minSize[1]]], options=undefined, skipAjaxValidation=undefined)jquery...gine.js (Zeile 402)
_onFieldEvent()jquery...gine.js (Zeile 183)
d(c=Object { originalEvent=Event blur, type="blur", mehr...})jquery....min.js (Zeile 16)
d(a=blur )jquery....min.js (Zeile 16)
[Bei diesem Fehler anhalten] options.isError = false;
```

Here I recommend another [jQuery validation plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/) for client side validation, which is sophisticated and is written by a jQuery core team member.

Comment: i wanted the floating bubble in their validation. so i am using that plaugin.